# Oracle XE for Linux...?

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle-xe

Is there a Linux version of Oracle XE?

I could not find any info on Oracles official site.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's available [here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/database/xe/htdocs/102xelinsoft.html).

You will find it in RPM and Deb packages.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I am using CentOS. Are there any versions for either CentOS or Suse?

Comment: AFIK, CentOs has a RPM-based Package Management System, so the RPM should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can download it @ http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/database/xe/htdocs/102xelinsoft.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what disto you have in mind, but ubuntu have included it in the package manager which makes it very easy to install, includes init scripts and everything you may need.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Oracle10g

Answer (score -1):

Seems a bit useless that they don't supply an x86_64 version; i386 is only really useful for toy servers.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/xe/index.html: "Oracle Database 10g Express Edition (Oracle Database XE) is an entry-level, small-footprint database .... [Oracle XE will] use up to 1GB of memory, and use one CPU on the host machine".